# Is there a computationally less expensive way to add a dataframe column if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a Spark Dataframe with an optional field X. If the field doesn't exist at all, I want to create it and set it equal to column A. If the field exists but is null, I want to set it equal to column A. If the field exists and is not null, I want to use the value already inside it.

I am currently doing it like this:

`val df = spark.read.json("records.json")
val dfWithColX = if (Try(df("X")).isSuccess) {
  df.withColumn("X", when(col("X").isNull, col("A")).otherwise(col("X")))
} else df.withColumn("X", col("A"))`

Is there a more performant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's more performant, but it seems better to just check without catching exceptions, like:

```
val dfWithColX = if (df.columns.contains("X")) {
  df.withColumn("X", coalesce('X, 'A))
} else {
  df.withColumn("X", 'A)
}
```